# How to create order programmatically with paypal payment method in Magento1.8

Tags: php, paypal, magento-1.8

I need to create a order different section in Magento admin panel. I have created a custom module for that. And here I am able to transfer data(Item, price) from my custom module's controller/action to Paypal. And it is showing item details in Paypal and it is paying successfully. and For that I have created a custom table. Here it redirects a success page after paying. But I don't know how to validate for security purpose. Any user can hit this url in browser. I have googled a lot.But there is no showing perfect solution. Here a link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70705/magento-create-order-programmatically-with-paypal-payment-method that I have seen.Here payment method,Paypal Express checkout has been used. But for that how to build up with Paypal Express checkout in my custom module and also how to get token after getting payment from Paypal. If any one knows about it, please reply me..Thank you